# Power Query OnEvent based scripting

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, powerquery

I'm having an issue with two things relating to PowerQuery in Excel 2016.  The first is that when I do a refresh in VBA the code doesn't stop for a DB connection error message, even without an On Error Resume Next type of line.  I would like for the user to know when there is a connection is, and more importantly for the script to Go To another line and bypass some code should one occur

The second issue is closely related to the first, I would like to notate a specific (named) cell with a date/time stamp of when the last refresh took place.

Note: This workbook has 4 Power Query loaded tables in it (created from appx 15 DB SQL Server DB queries through PwrQry).

This is the current code I have for a refresh all and timestamp

```
Sub RefreshALLdata()

'On Error GoTo Err

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

With Range("RefreshAllDateTime")
    .Value = Now()
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
End With

'Err:

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

When a friend of mine (Who doesn't have DB access) uses this code, it skips right past the failed connection message and adds the DataTime stamp regardless.  I tried with and then without the OnError coding to see if the error would pop up, but it doesn't even error out at all.

I'm hoping to create individual buttons for each page afterwards with a script that does a refresh of the listobject on current page and adds a timestamp for each table, but haven't gotten there yet.

Any guidance with regard to this matter would be very appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Sincerely,
Kris

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RefreshAlldata()

    With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - abc") ' My query was called abc, change to whatever yours is called.
        .OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False ' This should ensure VBA waits for the query to refresh before moving on to the next line of code.
        On Error GoTo RefreshFailed
        .Refresh
        On Error GoTo 0 ' We do not want to suppress/ignore non-refresh errors.
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    With Range("RefreshAllDateTime")
        .Value = Now()
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With

RefreshFailed:
    ActiveSheet.Protect ' Kind of redundant, due to On Error GoTo 0 and ActiveSheet.Unprotect only running if there was no error.
End Sub
```

Initially I thought your query might be refreshing asynchronously; meaning the VBA code moved on from the `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` line before the refresh actually finished; meaning you'd need to "disable background refresh".

But I created a query whose code deliberately raises an error (in Power Query). I found that, despite an expected error message appearing in Excel, my VBA code (using `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`) behaved as if there was no error. (By that I mean despite having `On Error GoTo Err`, the code would not jump to `Err`.)

To work around this, I removed `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` from my VBA code and replaced it with `ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - abc").Refresh` (where `abc` was the name of my query) and disabled background refresh. With that, VBA error handling began working as expected. That's the code I've provided above.

---

If the code above works for you (you'll need to change `abc` to whatever your query is called), then some small details if you have time:

- It might be better to create a function which tries to refresh a specified query -- and returns `True`/`False` indicating success. That way, you can call it for each of the 4 tables mentioned in your question. It also means, the `On Error GoTo ...` logic is confined to the `Boolean`-returning function, allowing the parent/main procedure to control program flow via regular `If` logic.
- For its own purposes, the code above disables background refresh (for the query) but does not restore the setting to its original state. You can change this by capturing the original setting's value in a variable and re-assigning it after the refresh (or upon error).
- Might be better to not use `Err` as a label, as I believe there is a global error object in VBA with the same identifier (which is why I changed it to `RefreshFailed`).
- Instead of `ActiveSheet`, it might better to refer to the worksheet by name (as there is no guarantee an object will be/remain "active" whilst the code is running). This includes the unqualified `Range` call.
- The `RefreshFailed` label is presently kind of redundant due to the presence of `On Error GoTo 0` and `ActiveSheet.Unprotect` only running if no error occurred. But I've left it in there in case you have other code you want to stick in there.

---

If needed, this was the query I used to raise an error in Power Query:

```
let
    Source = if false then 1 else error "Some contrived error."
in
    Source
```

It assumed that from VBA's perspective, the above error is "no different" than the error your code raises (when the database is inaccessible).

---

There might be other ways of doing this e.g. using events like `QueryTable_AfterRefresh`.